# How to trigger function only once when changing order status in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to trigger SMS whenever order change to a specific custom order status on WooCommerce. Here is my code below :

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'trigger_sms_on_new_status', 15, 4 );
function trigger_sms_on_new_status( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) { 
    
    $firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $phone     = $order->get_billing_phone();
    $shopname  = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_from_name');
    
    if( $order->has_status( 'confirmed' ) && $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) {
        $sms_text = "Bonjour $firstname, votre commande #$order_id de $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    } else if( $order->has_status( 'confirmed' ) && !( $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) ) {
        $sms_text = "Hello $firstname, your order #$order_id from $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text, $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    }

    if( $order->has_status( 'packing' ) && $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) {
        $sms_text = "Bonjour $firstname, votre commande #$order_id de $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    } else if( $order->has_status( 'packing' ) && !( $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) ) {
        $sms_text = "Hello $firstname, your order #$order_id from $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text, $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    }

    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) && $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) {
        $sms_text = "Bonjour $firstname, votre commande #$order_id de $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    } else if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) && !( $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" ) ) {
        $sms_text = "Hello $firstname, your order #$order_id from $shopname...";
        send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text, $shopname );
        $order->add_order_note( 'SMS sent with success.' );
    }
}
```

**Explaining my code :**

If order status is either "Confirmed", "Packing", or "Shipped" and billing country is FR or BE then it will sent an SMS in French corresponding to these statuses. Howewer, if billing country is not FR or BE, it will sent an SMS but in English.

- "$phone" take customer phone number from order and sent it to "send_sms_function" function where it will be use to sent SMS to.
- "$sms_text" is what SMS body needs to be for each condition.
- "send_sms_function( $phone, $sms_text $shopname )" trigger the function where Twilio API and settings are.

**Issues :**

As you can see, I am using "woocommerce_order_status_changed" hook, which works great to trigger custom emails classes I have also created.
Howewer, for this code, it will trigger the SMS for EACH order statuses in the code.

Example : I change order status from "On Hold" to "Confirmed". SMS will be sent for "Confirmed", "Packing" and "Shipped" order statuses, even though I have change status to "Confirmed" only.

Second problem is that it will be sent in French even if billing country is not "FR" or "BE".

So it looks like my code do not take condition in count and will send SMS for all statuses in code and only in first language.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looking at your code, you don't need to check if the language is _not_ FR or BE, since if the condition in the original `if` is not met, it will make it to the `else if`.  You can remove `&& !( $order->get_billing_country() == "FR" || "BE" )` from all of your `else if` since if the condition made it that far, FR and BE are already false. This may or may not solve your problem, but it removes unnecessary complications to check for. You may want to wrap your FR/BE check in parenthesis as well and change the the check to a more strict `===`.

Comment: Part: 2 `&& ( $order->get_billing_country() === "FR" || "BE ")` It seems like you could assign `$order->get_billing_country()` to a variable as well: `$billingcountry = $order->get_billing_country()` - again, makes it cleaner and easier to read.